# jQuery's nyroModal with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery, nyromodal

I'm using nyroModal plugin. By simply putting a setup scripts in the head tag and define a class attribute with nyroModal will make that link open as a modal window.

```
<a href="Page1.aspx" class="nyroModal">Show</a>
```

Now, `Page1.aspx` will open in a modal window. This page has a simple `asp:button` having a OnClick defined with empty body:

```
<asp:button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click"/>

void btn_Click(Object sender,  EventArgs e) {  }
```

If we click on the above link a window appears with a button and when I click on that button modal windows disappears (or break) and redirected to `Page1.aspx`.

Any idea, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following:

```
jQuery(function ($) { jQuery('.nyroModal').nyroModal({ 'blocker': '#Form' }); });
```

replace #Form with aspForm or whatever your form name is.